# JAVA Swing - Setting JLabel equal to a String in another class

Tags: java, swing, class, methods, jlabel

I have a method called `getTheUserInput` in a class which returns a String which updates based on user actions, which is located inside a class called Board.java. I have action which adds data to a String which I know works.

In my other class I have a JLabel which has been set to equal the returned String of the method, as follows:

```
JLabel l = new JLabel(b.getTheUserInput());
```

However, when I run the application no matter what input the user provides, the string updates, but the JLabel stays blank. How do I keep the JLabel updated consistently with the string in the other class?

Comment: The key is understanding the difference between a reference variable and the object it refers to. If a String variable `String foo = "bar";`, and later I change it to `foo = "baz";`, the foo variable refers to a different String object, but the **original "bar" String is unchanged**. The JLabel displays a String object and is tied to that String object, not to any String variable. The variable may later refer to a new String, but the JLabel still refers to the **same** String object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd .... need to update the `JLabel`.

```
myJLabel.setText(newString);
```

`String`s in Java are immutable so they can never change / be changed.

For example when you say, "I have action which adds data to a String which I know works." ... you're incorrect. You've created a new `String`. You need to supply the `JLabel` with the new `String` (the user's input) if you want to change the text.

**Edit:** To answer the last part of your question; you'd need to keep track of the `JLabel` and update it as I show above every time the user provides input (in the event handler for whatever that is). Using the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) might be an option as Java provides it via `Observer` and `Observable`

Comment: Great - thanks, @Brian Roach. I solved it by creating a JLabel in the Board.java class, then using the setText method to set the text to the updated text. And then set the getTheUserInput method to return the JLabel to the other class. Because this is essentially a reference to the JLabel, when the JLabel is updated, so does the getTheUserInput() field of the layout. Can I have confirmation that this is a acceptable way of doing it, and a sort of explanation of why when I have getTheUserInput to return a JLabel it works but doesn't for the String? Thank you!

Comment: The `JLabel` is a mutable object, so that works fine; you're changing something contained inside it and you have multiple references to the `JLabel`. A `String` on the other hand is immutable as I mentioned; when you do something like concatenation (e.g. `myString += someOtherString;`) you're not modifying `myString`. The concatenation is returning a new `String` object and assigning the reference to `myString` - this is now a *different* reference/object than the one you gave the JLabel.

Comment: @m92: I like Brian's approach better than yours (1+ up-vote) because it results in less [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_science)) meaning fewer classes have to know much about the innards of other classes, and this is a good thing (please check out the link).

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, so I have it working using the method I created above. But how would you implement it the way Brian Roach has pointed out, and why is it a better way of doing it? I haven't come across it before.

Comment: I would use a PropertyChangeListener for this. I'd give the class whose variable (a String) you want to watch a PropertyChangeSupport variable and an addPropertyChangeListener method and a removePropertyChangeListener method. And then in the watched variable's setter method, I'd call `firePropertyChange(...)` if the variable refers to a new String. For an example of this idea with Swing, please see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6088659/522444)

Answer (score 2):

That label is set by default with whatever gets returned by `b.getTheUserInput()` initially. If the output of `b.getTheUserInput()` changes, the label doesn't find out and so doesn't change its text.

The easiest way to fix this is to call `l.setText(b.getTheUserInput())` whenever `b.getTheUserInput()` has new output.

Another way is to write a listener (such as a [ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html)) that sends out an event whenever `b.getTheUserInput()` has new output, then have the label add the listener and change its text when an event is received. This may seem more complicated initially, but the advantage is that `Board` does not need to know about the label or anything else that might want to access its output in future.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities.

First is to update the text `l.setText(b.getTheUserInput());` other option is that you did not add the label to a container.

Comment: It would appear the OP thought he was giving the `JLabel` a pointer to a `String` and expected the `JLabel` to display changes made to that `String`. ; he doesn't understand that Strings are immutable (and that rarely does Java operate in such a manner even with mutable objects).

Comment: That might explain what OP had in mind saying `...has been set to equal the returned String...`. But really is now is hard to imagine the logic behind.