# how to displays the mouse XY coordinates in java popup menu?

Tags: java, swing, popupmenu, cartesian-coordinates

I having trouble displaying the x,y coordinates of the mouse on JPopupMenu under mouse pointer. the reason that i use JlayerPane in the code is to be able adding cartesian coordinate system dynamically to the JPopupMenu like what you can see in the CAD application.

**Does anyone know why it does not display while it paint correctly?**

```
public void show popupwindow(JPanel parentPanel, int xLocation, int yLocation){
    Box selectionBox = createSelectionBox();

    JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();

    // create an instance of my custom mouse cursor label
    XYMouseLabel mouseLabel = new XYMouseLabel();
    mouseLabel.setBounds(0, 0, selectionBox.getWidth(), selectionBox.getHeight());

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));

    JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    layeredPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Move the Mouse to get coordinate"));

    layeredPane.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
            super.mouseMoved(me);
            mouseLabel.x = me.getX();
            mouseLabel.y = me.getY();
            mouseLabel.repaint();
        }
    });

    layeredPane.add(mouseLabel , JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
    layeredPane.add(selectionBox, 2, 0);

    panel.add(layeredPane);
    popupMenu.add(panel);
    popupMenu.show(parentPanel , xLocation,yLocation)
 }

    public class XYMouseLabel extends JComponent {
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public XYMouseLabel() {
            this.setBackground(Color.green);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            //hier paint the cartesian coordinate system
            String s = x + ", " + y;
            g2.setColor(Color.red);
            g2.drawString(s, x, y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure, but IIRC `final` and `String` have a sideeffect on each other. Strings are immutable, so if you final a JLabel, I think you need to `.setText(me.getX().toString())` on it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071879/java-swing-setting-jlabel-equal-to-a-string-in-another-class

Comment: You create an instance of `XYMouseLabel` and assign it to `mouseLabel`, but this is then never added to anything. You add `alsXYMouseLabel` to the `layeredPane`, but I have no idea what that is

Comment: Sorry it was a typeo mistake what i have corrected. it should be mouseLabel

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.