# manage a button state in mainframe when opening a internalframe

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I just need to disable a button in mainframe when the button's actionperformed event fired and again enable it after the internal frame closed, I tried several method but all of them not working
I'm using netbeans here is what I'm trying to do

**mainframe class**

```
 package tt;

public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Test() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jDesktopPane1 = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jDesktopPane1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
            jDesktopPane1);
    jDesktopPane1.setLayout(jDesktopPane1Layout);
    jDesktopPane1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(jDesktopPane1Layout
            .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 578, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    jDesktopPane1Layout.setVerticalGroup(jDesktopPane1Layout
            .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 367, Short.MAX_VALUE));

    jButton1.setText("OPEN");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
            jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
            jPanel1Layout
                    .createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(136, 136, 136)
                    .addComponent(jButton1,
                            javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74,
                            javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                            Short.MAX_VALUE)));
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(
            jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 39, Short.MAX_VALUE));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
            getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout
            .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jDesktopPane1)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    layout.setVerticalGroup(layout
            .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(
                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jDesktopPane1)
                            .addPreferredGap(
                                    javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jPanel1,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)));

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jButton1.setEnabled(false);
    NewJInternalFrame nf = new NewJInternalFrame();
    jDesktopPane1.add(nf);
    nf.show();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {


    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager
                .getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(
                java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(
                java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(
                java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(
                java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    // </editor-fold>

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Test().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
public javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JDesktopPane jDesktopPane1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

**internalframe class**

```
  package tt;

   public class NewJInternalFrame extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

public NewJInternalFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    setClosable(true);
    setIconifiable(true);
    setMaximizable(true);
    setResizable(true);
    addInternalFrameListener(new javax.swing.event.InternalFrameListener() {
        public void internalFrameActivated(
                javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }

        public void internalFrameClosed(
                javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
            formInternalFrameClosed(evt);
        }

        public void internalFrameClosing(
                javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }

        public void internalFrameDeactivated(
                javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }

        public void internalFrameDeiconified(
                javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }

        public void internalFrameIconified(
                javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }

        public void internalFrameOpened(
                javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
            getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 394,
            Short.MAX_VALUE));
    layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 274,
            Short.MAX_VALUE));

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void formInternalFrameClosed(
        javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
    Test njf = new Test();
    njf.jButton1.setEnabled(true);
}


  }
```

[My test programme](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ui9t1e8fz8qkn6d/test.rar?dl=0)

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are the buttons not being disabled? Not being re-enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an InternalFrameListener to your JInternalFrame, and re-enable the JButton when the JInternalFrame is either closed or closing or both.

Or better still -- it looks as if you're trying to create and display the JInternalFrame equivalent of a JOptionPane, and if so, you can actually do this directly via JOptionPane showInternalXxxDialog as discussed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#create).

As an aside, your code posted shows some magical thinking:

```
private void formInternalFrameClosed(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {                                         
    posframe pos = new posframe(); // **** here***
    pos.jButton1.setEnabled(true);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"closed");
}
```

You're creating a new posframe (which by the way should be re-named PosFrame to comply with Java naming rules), and assuming that if you enable a JButton on this new posframe object, it will magically enable the JButton in the displayed posframe object, but please understand that that is not how Java works, that the two posframe objects are completely distinct, and setting the state of the non-displayed posframe will have no effect on the displayed one. If your code were to work, you'd first have to pass a reference of the displayed posframe object into the class that is calling this code above.

Also your code suggests that the jButton1 has been declared `public`, if so, that is a potentially dangerous thing to do and should be avoided.

---

**Edit**
OK, based on your posted code, I see two possible solutions to your issue.

1. Pass a reference of the main GUI into your JInternalFrame code

   - Use this reference to set a field of the class with the reference.
   - Then in the listener, call a **public** method on the main GUI (don't make fields public if at all possible).
2. Or an even better solution is to not have the JInternalFrame worry about that which should not concern it. Instead put the listener in the calling class, so that it changes itself without need for the other class to manipulate things that it really shouldn't have responsibility for.

Code for example one is shown below. Changes are noted by //!! comments.

```
public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   public Test() {
      initComponents();
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
   private void initComponents() {

      jDesktopPane1 = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
      jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
      jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

      setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      javax.swing.GroupLayout jDesktopPane1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
            jDesktopPane1);
      jDesktopPane1.setLayout(jDesktopPane1Layout);
      jDesktopPane1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(jDesktopPane1Layout
            .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 578, Short.MAX_VALUE));
      jDesktopPane1Layout.setVerticalGroup(jDesktopPane1Layout
            .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 367, Short.MAX_VALUE));

      jButton1.setText("OPEN");
      jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
         }
      });

      javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
            jPanel1);
      jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
      jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
            jPanel1Layout
                  .createSequentialGroup()
                  .addGap(136, 136, 136)
                  .addComponent(jButton1,
                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74,
                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                  .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                        Short.MAX_VALUE)));
      jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(jButton1,
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 39, Short.MAX_VALUE));

      javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
            getContentPane());
      getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
      layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout
            .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jDesktopPane1)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                  javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE));
      layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
            layout.createSequentialGroup()
                  .addComponent(jDesktopPane1)
                  .addPreferredGap(
                        javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                  .addComponent(jPanel1,
                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)));

      pack();
   }// </editor-fold>

   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      jButton1.setEnabled(false);
      NewJInternalFrame nf = new NewJInternalFrame(this);  //!! 
      jDesktopPane1.add(nf);
      nf.show();
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {

      try {
         for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager
               .getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
               javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
               break;
            }
         }
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(
               java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(
               java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(
               java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(
               java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
      // </editor-fold>

      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            new Test().setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }

   // Variables declaration - do not modify
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton1; //!! make this private
   private javax.swing.JDesktopPane jDesktopPane1;
   private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
   // End of variables declaration

   //!! added
   public void setButton1Enabled(boolean enabled) {
      jButton1.setEnabled(enabled);
   }
}

class NewJInternalFrame extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
   private Test test; //!!

   public NewJInternalFrame(Test test) { //!!
      this.test = test; //!!
      initComponents();
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
   private void initComponents() {

      setClosable(true);
      setIconifiable(true);
      setMaximizable(true);
      setResizable(true);
      addInternalFrameListener(new javax.swing.event.InternalFrameListener() {
         public void internalFrameActivated(
               javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
         }

         public void internalFrameClosed(
               javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
            formInternalFrameClosed(evt);
         }

         public void internalFrameClosing(
               javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
         }

         public void internalFrameDeactivated(
               javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
         }

         public void internalFrameDeiconified(
               javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
         }

         public void internalFrameIconified(
               javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
         }

         public void internalFrameOpened(
               javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
         }
      });

      javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
            getContentPane());
      getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
      layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 394,
            Short.MAX_VALUE));
      layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 274,
            Short.MAX_VALUE));

      pack();
   }// </editor-fold>

   private void formInternalFrameClosed(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
      //!! Test njf = new Test();
      //!! njf.jButton1.setEnabled(true);
      test.setButton1Enabled(true); //!! don't expose the button but a method
   }

}
```

Partial code for the second solution is noted below:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   jButton1.setEnabled(false);
   NewJInternalFrame nf = new NewJInternalFrame();
   jDesktopPane1.add(nf);
   nf.show();

   // !! do all this in the calling code
   nf.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
         jButton1.setEnabled(true);
      }

   });
}
```

Comment: actually the messagebox is just for the confirmation to get that the function worked properly.and of course, that is what i have done as i mentioned above. i used internalframeclosed event but it's not working

Comment: the real magic is it's not working at all. I think the reference passing method is right. can you give me some sample codes to do that

Comment: @ChathurangaSandaruwan: I can only give you samples based on what you've posted, and at present it's not much. Please consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I will be happy to try to revise it, but please first read the link before posting. You'll also want to avoid any NetBeans generated code when creating this code.

Comment: @ChathurangaSandaruwan: here is some sample code from a previous answer of mine regarding passing references in Swing GUI's: [example code answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9475111/522444).

Comment: thanx for your quick reply hovercraft but the problem when i'm trying your constructor passing method i cant create my second frame instant in another place like                              if1 if11 = new if1(); 
 jDesktopPane1.add(if11);  
 if11.show();

Comment: @ChathurangaSandaruwan: create your [minimal program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), show me your problem, and let's get to the bottom of this and solve it.

Comment: well i just created it for the first time please kindly avoid any mistakes and the internalframe is currently not have any components just a basic one so didnt include the code

Comment: @ChathurangaSandaruwan: please re-read this link:[mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), your posted code needs to be compilable and runnable without altering it *by me*, and right now that's impossible as it has no imports, it refers to Files that I don't have, it calls methods that aren't included, including `initComponents()`, it refers to classes that I don't have, such as if2. Please if I'm to help you, please help me out by posting a small program that I can actually run, test and modify. Yes, I am asking extra work from you,  but you're of course asking for work and effort from us.

Comment: sorry friend i will make another programme and send the codes

Comment: @ChathurangaSandaruwan Also there's no main method.

Comment: this netbeans is  making  load of automated codes,its very hard for remove unnecessary things as a noob :)

Comment: i dont think i can make this doucment properly if i put a link can you download my source files and check it

Comment: @ChathurangaSandaruwan: Do what you can to try to create the briefest thing that runs that you can. I know that you can do it.

Comment: i jsut edited my programme,and that i can do for make it run in eclipse and now you can copy past it to run programme,it should run now

Comment: @ChathurangaSandaruwan: your test program works! Let me work on it for a few, but 1+ to your question for the wonderful effort -- thanks!

Comment: @ChathurangaSandaruwan: you're welcome! And thanks for creating your small program. As you see, it is a useful tool to know.