# Separating code into classes (GUI specific) using Java

Tags: java, class, menu, actionlistener

In a sample program I have one class that places:

- GUI components on a JPanel which is inside a JFrame.
- A method makeMenu to create a menu bar
- An ActionListener inside the makeMenu method to change the JPanels background           color when called.
- Main method.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

     private JPanel jPanelRight;
     private JPanel jPanelLeft;
     JMenuBar menuBar;
     JMenu file, help;
     JMenuItem changeColor;

    public GUI() {
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       this.setJMenuBar(makeMenu()); // call constructor to create the menu
       this.setSize(800, 600); // set frame size
       this.setVisible(true); // display frame
       this.setTitle("understanding objects");
       setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // layout manager

    jPanelLeft = new JPanel(); //left jpanel
    jPanelLeft.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 800));  // to set the size of the left panel
    jPanelLeft.setBackground(Color.blue);

    jPanelRight = new JPanel(); //right jpanel
    jPanelRight.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 600));  // to set the size of the right panel
    jPanelRight.setBackground(Color.green);

    this.add(jPanelLeft, BorderLayout.WEST); //add jpanel to the left side of the frame
    this.add(jPanelRight, BorderLayout.EAST); //add jpanel to the right side of the frame

    }//end constructor 

    public JMenuBar makeMenu() {

    menuBar = new JMenuBar(); //menu bar
    file = new JMenu("File"); //menu item
    menuBar.add(file);
    help = new JMenu("Help"); //menu item
    menuBar.add(help);


    changeColor = new JMenuItem("Change Colour"); //sub menu item
    changeColor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jPanelRight.setBackground(Color.red);
        }
    });
    file.add(changeColor);

    return menuBar;
     }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            new GUI();

          }

       });

     } // end 
    }//end class
```

I am trying to separate the code into 3 or 4 classes.

- GUI class
- ActionListener class
- MakeMenu class
- Main class (to run program)

one problem that keeps occurring is that i when i separate the code i can only change using System.out.println(); and can not change the GUI i.e. i can print out that the jPanelRight is now red but can not actually change the jPanelRight to red.

I am possibly going about this the wrong way.
A GUI to use a different class to create its menu and another different class to control the actions for the GUI's menu.

Comment: probably your question is suitable for Code Review ,

Comment: Give your GUI public mutator and accessor methods that other classes can call, and pass instances where needed. Better still, model your program into an MVC-like structure.

Comment: thanks, i have tried to adapt my program to MVC using your code from this question:                                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087436/how-to-work-with-swing-with-multiple-classes                                                                                               and i am struggling. Could you help with the first part of your comment (Putting GUI public mutator and accessor methods that other classes can call) is it supplying getters and setters for each element in the GUI ? as this would be a lot of code.